# Increase level of accuracy to get the closest address when a button is tapped using CoreLocation

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

What I want, is to be able to walk outside in the driveway of a house and get the address for that house when a button is tapped.

The code below works fine except that I sometimes don't get the right address the first time the button is tapped, I have to tap the button a few times.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    @IBAction func myLocation(_ sender: Any) {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)-> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print("Reverse geocoder failed with error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            if placemarks!.count > 0 {
                let placemark = placemarks![0]
                self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

                print("Address: \(placemark.name!) \(placemark.locality!), \(placemark.administrativeArea!) \(placemark.postalCode!)")

            }else{
                print("No placemarks found.")
            }
        })
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Location manager error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }   
}
```

As you can see I'm stopping updating location as soon as a placemark is found, is there something that can be done here to improve accuracy.

What would be the logic to increase the level of accuracy to get the closest address when the button is tapped?

Comment: Core Location begins returning location coordinates as soon as it can, however it will continue to do so as long as you let it. It will keep trying to increase the accuracy of those coordinates. You can choose to keep accepting those coordinates until the accuracy is acceptable, e.g. 50m, 10m... GPS doesn’t return your exact location as soon as you ask it to.

Comment: I'm not sure how to keep checking the accuracy.  Maybe `if placemarks!.count > 5 `.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT how to check

There is a timestamp attribute for every CLLocation object, compare it to `now`
(before calling the geocoder)

```
let howRecent = newLocation.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow
guard newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 20 && abs(howRecent) < 10 else { continue }
```

First, before you call the geocode, you should check `manager.location`'s timestamp as suggested by [the doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423687-location?language=objc), because you may receive a cached data that's not really reflective of the current location.

Second, you may want to consider using `locationManager.requestLocation()`, it reports a location to fit your `desiredAccuracy`, and stops automatically.

Finally you can always check the location object to see if you have enough accuracy before sending to the geocode, if it doesn't, start over again.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a little more on how to check the timestamp and location object?

Comment: I'm not sure where did `newLocation` come from? Do I have to iterate the `CLLocation` objects in a for loop before the `CLGeocoder`?

Comment: @fs_tigre you can loop for the ‘locations’ (parameter of the delegate function) or it can be just ‘manager.location’